# query with name and time spent with max views

Tags: mysql

I am having data like this database table:

```
cookie_id   cookie_name     cookie_url  cookie_view     date    time
     1       S265nEmXMz     /test.php      1         23/11/16   02:51:39
     2       S265nEmXMz     /test.php      2         23/11/16   02:52:45
     3       5h2Rae6YRO     /test.php      1         23/11/16   02:52:58
```

I want to get cookie_name having max number of views and substraction of max to min time like

```
   cookie_id cookie_name    cookie_url  cookie_view     date    time
     1       S265nEmXMz     /test.php      2         23/11/16   00:01:06

     2       5h2Rae6YRO     /test.php      1         23/11/16   02:52:58
```

Comment: The desired result is weird. First of all, `cookie_id` does not align with original data, and for the first data entry, `00:01:06` comes from nowhere.

Comment: how is the time being changed in the desired output?

Comment: i need to substract 02:52:45 - 02:51:39 so i.e ; 00:01:06 time

Comment: You'd better post-process your output with server-side script, e.g. PHP

Comment: I want it in query...php how ? @Raptor

Comment: Can you at least try some coding first ?

Comment: I already tried with my query SELECT max( cookie_view ) , max( time ) , min( time ) , cookie_name, date
FROM `cookie_table`
GROUP BY cookie_name
LIMIT 0 , 30 its working but time diffrence not getting @Raptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [subtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subtime) to get the time difference. The other detail is that you need CASE for when you only have one cookie to avoid getting 0 as time.

```
 SELECT `cookie_id`,
       `cookie_name`,
       `cookie_url`,
       MAX(`cookie_view`) cookie_views,
       `date`,
       ( CASE
           WHEN Count(`cookie_id`) > 1 THEN Subtime(Max(`time`), Min(`time`))
           ELSE time
         end ) time_in
FROM   `cookies`
GROUP  BY `cookie_name`
ORDER  BY cookie_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 SELECT cookie_name, 
       cookie_url, 
       Max(cookie_view) AS maxview, 
       Subtime(Max(time), Min(time)) AS spent, 
       date 
FROM   `cookie_table` 
GROUP  BY cookie_name
```